# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle; why is this wrong?

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

I'm unsure where I'm going wrong with this.

In a class of 40 people studying music: 2 play violin, piano and recorder, 7 play at least violina nd piano, 6 play at least piano and recorder, 5 play at least recorder and violin, 17 play at least violin, 19 play at least piano, and 14 play at least recorder. How many play none of these instruments?

This is what I did:
$|A| = $ plays violin
$|B| = $ plays piano
$|C| = $ plays recorder.
From the information:
$|A\cap B\cap C| = 2 \\ |A\cup B| = 7 \\ |A\cup C|  =5 \\ |B \cup C| = 6 \\ |A| = 17 \\ |B| = 19 \\ |C| = 14.$

I want $|A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c|$.
By considering
$$|A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c| = |A^c| + |B^c| + |C^c| - |A^c\cap B^c| - |A^c \cap C^c| - |B^c \cap C^c| + |A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c|\\ = (40-17)+(40-19) + (40-14) - (40-7) - (40-5) + (40-6) + |A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c|\\ = -32 + |A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c| = 40 - |A \cap B \cap C| = 38 \\ \implies |A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c| = 70...?$$

Comment: How is $A^c\cap B^c$ larger than $A^c?$ In general, $X\cap Y\subseteq Y$.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's also why I got a negative answer for a cardinality.

Comment: 7 Play violin and piano should be "$|A \cap B| = 7$".  Also, $A \cup B$ is the set of those who play violin OR piano, including those who only play 1 instrument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations for the pairs is wrong. $|A^c\cap B^c|=40-|A\cup B|$, and you don't know $|A\cup B|$. You are computing it as $|A^c\cap B^c|=40-|A\cap B|$, which is false.

Instead, just computes $|A\cup B\cup C|$ with inclusion-exclusion, and then subtract from $40$.

Comment: Did I interpret the question incorrectly then?

Comment: What above indicates I think you interpreted the question incorrectly? I'm showing the error that you made, and suggesting an alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, take the information you know. Your events for more than 1 instrument should be intersections, not unions. That is $\cap$ not $\cup$

> $|A\cap B\cap C| = 2 \\ |A\cap B| = 7 \\ |A\cap C|  =5 \\ |B \cap C| =
> 6 \\ |A| = 17 \\ |B|
>  = 19 \\ |C| = 14.$

You want $|A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c|$ which is simply $40-|A \cup B \cup C|$

Then for $|A \cup B \cup C|$ we have $|A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A\cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cup B \cup C|$

$=17+19+14-7-5-6+2=34$

Don't forget final step of $40-34=6$